# How does the timing work on damage redirection?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

In Sentinels of the Multiverse, the villain Apostate has a card called the *Orb of Delirium*.  This card has 12hp, and it says: "Whenever a Villain Relic other than this card would be dealt Damage, redirect that Damage to this card."

Suppose that Apostate has the Orb in play and has three other relics.  Suppose that I use a power (for example, Tempest's area-of-effect attack) that deals 6 damage to each non-hero target.  Does this damage any relics other than the orb?

In other words, do I do this:

- deal 6 damage to the orb
- deal 6 damage to relic 2, redirect damage to the orb, orb dies
- deal 6 damage to relic 3
- deal 6 damage to relic 4

Or do I do this:

- deal 6 damage to the orb
- deal 6 damage to relic 2, redirect damage to the orb
- deal 6 damage to relic 3, redirect damage to the orb
- deal 6 damage to relic 4, redirect damage to the orb
- the orb dies

If any relics other than the orb do get damaged, do I get to choose which ones, or does it happen in a specific order?

Comment: My guess is it would act the same like in this question: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29843/how-does-the-timing-work-when-area-of-effect-damage-creates-new-targets . So basically the orb dies after the second redirect, and then the rest of the damage goes to 3 and 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a case like this you would chose the order that the damage happened one card at a time. If your goal was to destroy as many of the relics as possible you would do the damage something like this.

1. 6 damage to the orb
2. 6 damage to the relic you don't want destroyed this redirects to the orb destroying it
3. 6 damage to the next relic
4. 6 damage to the next relic

By remembering that each time you do damage it is considered separately, and if a response happens because of that damage then it takes place before the next damage from the original source is done. This is something that is important to remember and doing it all in the correct order can be the difference between winning and losing a game.

The only thing that needs to be done in the order they came out is the start/end of turn effects on a card. Such as the what happens during the villain/environment turn.

Comment: I'm glad to hear this, but do you have a rules citation?  Is this in the original rulebook, or in official errata or an FAQ somewhere?

Comment: This is how it works in the digital version of the game. You can watch many of the podcasts and see them chose the order of damage.

Comment: "By remembering that each time you do damage it is considered separately, and if a response happens because of that damage then it takes place before the next damage from the original source is done." This is the key, think of it like state-based actions in MTG: after every action (dealing damage, drawing a card, etc) check to see if a target has zero or fewer hitpoints, remove it if so. Also, check to see there are any triggers that respond to that action and resolve those before continuing with any further actions. The Digital App is an excellent resource for these sorts of "order" questions

Answer (score 1):

It should be the former. I can't really think of any thing to use as proof except watching [the Twitch Stream](https://www.twitch.tv/handelabragames) where they play the digital version of Sentinels. Damage is resolved one card at a time. In your second example the only way that would occur is if all the artifacts were damaged at once.

Instead the artifacts should be damaged in order from first out the last out each time redirecting when possible.

Comment: +1 and thanks!  Proof by "this is how the digital version works" is pretty good, but I'll hold off on accepting this answer until I see if someone has a stronger rules citation.  :)

Comment: That is incorrect, the damage does not depend on the order they came out in.