# How does the timing work when area-of-effect damage creates new targets?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

In Sentinels of the Multiverse, the villain Gloomweaver has this power: "Whenever a Cultist is destroyed, search the Villain trash for a Zombie card and put it into play."

Suppose that I use a power that "deals three damage to all non-hero targets".  If this power kills a Cultist and thus brings a Zombie into play, does the power also deal three damage to the Zombie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would do damage to the zombie. The reason for this is that in a case like this when a card is damaged/destroyed if it or another card has a reaction in response to this resolution on the current card stops until the second card is finished.

So what would happen is 3 damage is done to the cultist killing it. This triggers the ability that adds a zombie into the field of play pausing the ability that does 3 damage to all non hero targets until the zombie is in play. Once the ability that is doing the damage resumes there will be another target in play for it to damage.

This is important for a similar situation with ae damage and a card like the sonic mine that damages hero cards and prevents them from doing damage. When it dies it will prevent the rest of the AE damage from happening.

Answer (score 4):

Cards are resolved in order. So for instance in this scenario if you deal your damage you might look like this:

1. Gloomweaver 3 damage (Because he's the first card that came out) *<-- not actually true, damage is dealt in player's choice order*
2. Environment Card (Because something has been sticking around)
3. Villain Card (Dead; Add Zombie)
4. Villain Card (3 Damage)
5. New Zombie (3 Damage)

So yes you would do that damage to the zombie.

Comment: That is incorrect, cards effects happen based on order of play. Dealing damage is entirely up to the players and you can choose any order you want. In your example you can damage the cultists first and then the zombie.

Comment: agreed that is a mistake on my part but in either case the newly spawned zombie would still take damage.